# AttributeError: module 'kornia' has no attribute 'get_perspective_transform'

Tags: python, pytorch, kornia

i am just get github code and while run it give this error
i found for solution and get kornia official code for get perspective transform
KORNIA SITE CODE : https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/tutorials/warp_perspective.html  ,
error is at bottom of the line in this code  ,
error says : AttributeError: module 'kornia' has no attribute 'get_perspective_transform'

```
import torch
import kornia
points_src = torch.tensor([[
    [125., 150.], [562., 40.], [562., 282.], [54., 328.],
]])
h, w = 64, 128 
points_dst = torch.tensor([[
    [0., 0.], [w - 1., 0.], [w - 1., h - 1.], [0., h - 1.],
]])
############################################### ERROR AT HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!########################
M: torch.tensor = kornia.get_perspective_transform(points_src, points_dst)
############################################### ERROR AT HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!########################
```

Comment: What is the `kornia` version that you're using?

Comment: Latest version warp perspective [docs](https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.transform.html#warp-operators)

Comment: i am using 0.6.3.dev0 version of kornia @Kishore

Comment: You're referring to version 0.5's documentation and it seems that they have made some changes which are not backward compatible. You have to either use version 0.5 or refer to the latest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kornia.geometry.transform.imgwarp import get_perspective_transform
```